# Animação em Canvas causando serrilhamento nas imagens

Tags: javascript, canvas

Criei um [jogo](https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/Flappy-Bird), utilizando JS e Canvas, e quando o usuário inicia o jogo, o cenário e seus objetos começam a movimentar-se. A animação dele é feita através de um `requestAnimationFrame`, que é executado constantemente.

Abaixo está um código que, apesar de não ser o código exato do meu jogo, possui o mesmo conceito do que eu estou fazendo:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let positionX = 0;
let velocity = 10;

function update() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = "#f00";
    context.fillRect(positionX, canvas.height / 2, 50, 50);

    positionX += velocity;
    velocity += velocity == 30 ? 0 : 0.01;

    if (positionX > canvas.width) {
        positionX = -50;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" style="background-color: #000;"></canvas>
```

O problema é que no meu jogo (e até mesmo algumas vezes no exemplo acima, mas é difícil de perceber), algumas imagens ficam "tremendo", como se fossem imagens de "televisões antigas".

Por exemplo, nas imagens dos tubos do meu jogo, onde esse problema é mais nítido, a borda preta dele fica serrilhada, ou então, parte da imagem dele fica cheia de linhas bem finas vindas de baixo para cima. Acredito que isso esteja acontecendo devido à quantidade de imagens sendo movimentadas na tela do Canvas.

Para solucionar esse problema, eu tentei definir a propriedade `context.imageSmoothingQuality` para `"high"`, mas isso não fez efeito algum. O que eu posso fazer para resolver este problema?

Comment: A conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127191/discussion-on-question-by-jeanextreme002-animacao-em-canvas-causando-serrilhamen)